# odoo version 10 javascript error, failed modules

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, erp

I'm trying to start a small page but it doesn't work

I am using odoo 10, I have the website module installed but apparently it throws some mistakes

main.js

```py
odoo.define('gencontratos.main_page',function(require){
    "use strict";

    var Widget = require('web.Widget');

    var RootPage = Widget.extend({
        template:'qwebRoot',

        start:function(){
            console.log(this.$el);

            console.log('start----------');
        }
    })

    var page = new RootPage();
    //page.setElement('#root');
    page.appendTo('#root');
    console.log('loaded---------------------');

})
```

root.xml

```xml
<templates id="templates" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="qwebRoot">
        <div>
            qweb
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

```
error: Some modules could not be started web.assets_common.js:2995:302
Missing dependencies:     
Array(4) [ "web.web_client", "web_editor.editor", "web_editor.summernote", "web_editor.transcoder" ]
web.assets_common.js:2995:431
```

```
Failed modules:           
Array [ "gencontratos.main_page" ]
web.assets_common.js:2996:24
```

```
Rejected modules:         
Array(4) [ "website_portal", "website_payment.website_payment", "website_sale.website_sale_category", "website_sale.website_sale" ]
web.assets_common.js:2997:26
```

```
Non loaded modules:       
Array(16) [ "web.ChangePassword", "web.Apps", "account.reconciliation", "website_sale.backend", "mail.chat_client_action", "mail.ExtendedChatWindow", "mail.composer", "mail.chat_manager", "mail.Chatter", "mail.systray", … ]
```

I need help, I am starting a project for this version but it does not work, I have been missing for two days trying to solve this problem, the documentation does not say anything that can help me and on the Internet I have not found anything that could help me